# WP Rest API Querying Custom Posts by ACF fields

Tags: custom-post-types, advanced-custom-fields, rest-api

I have custom posts that represent real estate property and they have an ACF field of price. I'm trying to use the WP Rest API to query a certain price range, but to no avail.

E.g. querying the following URL returns all items rather than specific ones:

```
http://localhost/wp-json/wp/v2/property?filter[meta_query][relation]=AND&filter[meta_query][0][key]=price&filter[meta_query][0][value]=0&filter[meta_query][0][compare]=>&filter[meta_query][1][key]=price&filter[meta_query][1][value]=2681724&filter[meta_query][1][compare]=<
```

Even querying a specific price returns all items, e.g.:

```
http://localhost/wp-json/wp/v2/property?filter[meta_key]=price&filter[meta_value]=3000000
```

I've already added the relevant variables via the rest_query_vars filter:

```
function bones_allow_meta_query( $vars ) {    
    $vars[] = 'meta_key';
    $vars[] = 'meta_value';
    $vars[] = 'meta_query';

    return $vars;
}
add_filter( 'rest_query_vars', 'bones_allow_meta_query' );
```

It seems as though the filter query is completely ignored. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Couldn't get it to work. The only solution that I found was to setup a custom endpoint:

http://v2.wp-api.org/extending/adding/